# Use choice key with choices setting booleans

Tags: expl3, key-value, l3keys

When defining choice keys with `l3keys2e` there are two possible ways and I use the one with sub-keys in a new package. When defining watch each value should do `interface3.pdf` says that I can use `.code` which is done for `key-b` in the following example but I’d like to set the booleans directly with `.bool_set` as can be seen in `key-a`. Unfortunatly this doesn’t seem to work: When using `key-a=ch-a` as option the compilation hangs.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.sty}
% load xparse and identify package
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage{test}{2014/05/20}{0}{}

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% define bools for key-b
\bool_new:N \l_test_key_b_a_bool
\bool_new:N \l_test_key_b_b_bool
% define keys
\keys_define:nn { testkeys } {
   % this won't work
   key-a .choice:,
      key-a / ch-a .bool_set:N = \l_test_key_a_a_bool,
      key-a / ch-b .bool_set:N = \l_test_key_a_b_bool,
   % this will work
   key-b .choice:,
      key-b / ch-a .code:n = { \bool_set_true:N \l_test_key_b_a_bool },
      key-b / ch-b .code:n = { \bool_set_true:N \l_test_key_b_b_bool },
}
\ProcessKeysOptions{ testkeys }

% demo-commands (real life is more complex ...)
\NewDocumentCommand { \getChoiceA } { } {
   \bool_if:NT \l_test_key_a_a_bool { ch-a }
   \bool_if:NT \l_test_key_a_b_bool { ch-b }
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \getChoiceB } { } {
   \bool_if:NT \l_test_key_b_a_bool { ch-a }
   \bool_if:NT \l_test_key_b_b_bool { ch-b }
}
\end{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
%   key-a=ch-a,% uncomment this line to see the problem
   key-b=ch-a
]{test}

\begin{document}
   Choice of key-a was: \getChoiceA

   Choice of key-b was: \getChoiceB
\end{document}
```

Is it a bug that `.bool_set` can’t be used her or are there some smart considerations I don’t see?

Comment: Could you explain how you expect the first approach to work? I don't see where the user is supposed to supply the `true`/`false` input.

Comment: @JosephWright: As Jura said in his (her?) answer I had a little fallacy. I wanted `key-a/ch-a` to set the boolean `true` without a possibility to reset the bool / set it to `false`. SO maybe the current implementation is fine and kept me from doing some illogical. I need to think again how to implement another solution to reset the option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does look like a bug to me, or at least highly non-ideal behaviour.

Keys defined with the `.bool_set:N` property do technically expect to be given a value (either `true` or `false`). Notice that the property of the key `key-a / ch-a` isn't `.bool_set_true:N`. In fact, such a property isn't implemented in `l3keys` at present. So an argument could be made that the way you define `key-a` goes against the intended syntax, while the way you define `key-b` is correct.

However, the crucial difference between a nested case like yours and the non-nested case like

```
\keys_define:nn { testkeys } { key-c .bool_set:N = \l_test_key_c_bool }
\keys_set:nn { testkeys } { key-c }
```

is that in the non-nested case, the boolean *will* be set to `true` by default if no value is provided. The same happens if you pass `key-a / ch-a` instead of `key-a = ch-a` to your package.

Adding an explicit default for `ch-a` to your code with

```
\keys_define:nn { testkeys } 
  { 
    key-a / ch-a .default:n = { true } ,
    key-a / ch-b .default:n = { true } 
  }
```

doesn't help either. Passing `key-a = { ch-a = true }` produces an error because in that case `l3keys` looks for a choice under `key-a` that's called  "`ch-a=true`" instead of passing `true` to `ch-a`.

Finally, the fact that the compilation of your code hangs instead of producing an error is a good sign that something's gone wrong inside `l3keys`. I don't know the details of the implementation off the top of my head, and I don't have time today to dig into the source to see what's amiss—but there are actual experts here who can do a much better job of that anyway! In the meantime, it looks like what you've done with `key-b` is the way to go.

### Update (21 May 2014, 19:40 GMT)

A perusal of `source3` reveals the following underlying cause of the problem. In order to ensure that the a key defined with the `.bool_set:N` property only accepts `true` and `false` as values, it is internally defined as a choice key. In effect, writing

```
\keys_define:nn { testkeys } { key-c .bool_set:N = \l_test_key_c_bool }
```

is equivalent to writing

```
\keys_define:nn { testkeys } 
  { 
    key-c           .choice:                                              ,
    key-c           .default:n = { true }                                 ,
    key-c / true    .code:n    = { \bool_set_true:N  \l_test_key_c_bool } ,
    key-c / false   .code:n    = { \bool_set_false:N \l_test_key_c_bool } ,
    key-c / unknown .code:n    = 
      \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { kernel } { boolean-values-only }
        { \l_keys_key_tl } ,
  }
```

Since nesting choice keys (quite reasonably) doesn't work, defining one of the choices of a another choice key with `.bool_set:N` doesn't work. Indeed, because of the way the paths of choice keys are set, doing what you did with your `key-a` leads to an endless loop, just like the following

```
\keys_define:nn { testkeys } 
  { 
    foo                 .choice:                ,
    foo                 .default:n = { bar }    ,
    foo / bar           .choice:                ,
    foo / bar           .default:n = { bar-a }  ,
    foo / bar / bar-a   .code:n    = { BAR-A }  ,
    foo / bar / bar-b   .code:n    = { BAR-B }  ,
    foo / buzz          .choice:                ,
    foo / buzz          .default:n = { buzz-a } ,
    foo / buzz / buzz-a .code:n    = { BUZZ-A } ,
    foo / buzz / buzz-b .code:n    = { BUZZ-B } ,
  }
\keys_set:nn { testkeys } { foo = bar }
```

While I think this behaviour is fine for self-evident choice keys, I don't think it's right for `.bool_set:N`, so I'll send a fix request to the `latex3` mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. I’ll accept it since the “wrong syntax” argument is convincing. But a more intuitive way in future versions of L3 would be nice :-)

Comment: Okay, I've now looked at `source3` and figured out what goes wrong. I've edited the answer to make it a more complete.